# T-SQL, rows where a specific column does not change over a date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table structured like so:

```
ID        Date        purchaseType
01        03-01-18    apple
01        04-01-18    apple
02        05-01-18    spinach
01        05-01-18    apple
02        06-01-18    spinach
02        07-01-18    apple
...
```

I want to look at all Id's where the purchase type was the same over 3 months. That is to say, the results I would get from the above table would be:

```
ID    purchaseType    Length(months)
01    apple           3
...
```

and ID=02 is not included, as in the third month, the purchase type was switched to apple from spinach. I hope this makes sense!

Edit: There is always a record per month and ID, There should not be any duplicate records (That is to say, one purchase type, per ID, per month). It is always on the first of the month.

Edit2: I have tried doing something along the lines of

```
select Min(Date) as 'Min', max(date) as 'Max',ID,purchaseType
From someTableName
GroupBy ID,purchasetype
```

but not sure where to take it from here

Edit 3: I don't need a specific date range. Just if for an ID:X, if there at anypoint existed a 3 month period where purchase type did not change.

Comment: Please explain the data structure.  Is there always a record for month and an `id`?  Could there be multiple records?  Is it always on the first of the month?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added in the edit!

Comment: Group by month and check the count

Comment: @Eric I did a DateDiff group by, put the code in the edit. I feel like I can self join on that, however there are no unique ID's in the table (I know I know :(...) but I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Which 3 months?  ID=1 has no data for  months 6 or 7.  But if it did have June Spinach and July Spinach, would it still qualify for 3 months of Apple?   And if it had August Spinach would it report both 3/Apple and 3/Spinach?  or just the most recent 3/Spinach?  We need to know more about the data and the reporting requirements.  Also, consecutive 3 months? or with a gap?

Comment: does it needs to be consecutive months? what about if spinach had May, June and September, would it count for 3 months of spinach?

Comment: @donPablo the data will have gaps where there wasn't a "Purchase". I can do something like Max/min and a groupby, but the reporting requires that for all 3 months, they are in a row. So for month 1,2, and 3, they are all the same purchaseType. It should not matter whether those 3 months are june july august, or jan feb march. Hope that explains well!

Comment: would it report both 3/Apple and 3/Spinach? or just the most recent 3/Spinach?  Please modify the input data and the expected results in the above examples

Comment: @donPablo , I don't actually need the specific 3 month period, just if for ID=X, if there existed a 3 month period that had the same purchaseType. Will update description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my contribution, for requirements known to date.

(I needed to change ID as string to Idnum as int.)

```
CREATE TABLE #my_table
    (     IDnum          INTEGER 
        , DATEp          DATE
        , PurchaseType   VARCHAR(10)    )

    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '01', '03-01-18', 'apple'   );
    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '01', '04-01-18', 'apple'   );
    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '02', '05-01-18', 'spinach' );
    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '01', '05-01-18', 'apple'   );
    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '02', '06-01-18', 'spinach' );
    INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES( '02', '07-01-18', 'apple'   );

SELECT
    M1.IDnum
  , M1.PurchaseType
FROM #my_table AS M1
INNER JOIN #my_table AS M2
    ON M1.IDnum = M2.IDnum 
   AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, M1.DATEp) = M2.DATEp
INNER JOIN #my_table AS M3
    ON M1.IDnum = M3.IDnum 
   AND DATEADD(MONTH, 2, M1.DATEp) = M3.DATEp
WHERE M1.PurchaseType = M2.PurchaseType 
  AND M1.PurchaseType = M3.PurchaseType
GROUP BY
    M1.IDnum
  , M1.PurchaseType

-- RESULT:
--         IDnum  PurchaseType
--           1      apple
```

Comment: donPablo -   I hope you don't mind me converting your excellent code unto a self-running example.  (If you do, I can change it back.)

Comment: @Smandoli  I love it, and will try to remember to do the same on future solutions.  And to include the result.  (ID needed to be change 'cause of SYLK when loading xls from txt)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I understand the problem like this.  You want to find 3 months of more with no gap and no product change.  If a product was purchased there will exist a item in that month.

First you have gaps -- or hills and valleys.  There is a trick to do this.  You have two row numbers -- one based on increment every month and another on the value changing -- the difference of these two will give you "groups".   Then you need to look at the max and the min per group.

---

*prior answer*

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, PURCHASE_TYPE 
FROM (
  SELECT ID, PURCHASE_TYPE, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, PURCHASE_TYPE ORDER BY DATE) AS RN
  FROM your_table_name_goes_here
) X
WHERE RN >= 3
```

Comment: Based on comments, the OP requires consecutive months.  This solution doesn't handle that requirement: if you change the bottom-most record to `08-01-18`, this will still show 'apple' in the results.

Comment: Correction... a true test would be changing the top-most to `02-01-18`.